# Creating map through atlas defined by attributes

Tags: qgis, atlas, atlas-generator

I am trying to automate the creation of maps using atlas. I have a shapefile with the location of different big cat species in an area of Africe. I want to plot each species on a different map. The shapefile has a field for species with all the different species named (lion, tiger etc.). Each map should have the same extents the only difference is the species shown in each map.

Is this possible to achieve through the use of atlas?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,set atlas parameter as this picture.

[image]

Secondly set map extend with map properties >>> extend